# libavcodec.so.56 not found when running software compiled with opencv

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, libavcodec, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 16.04. Now every time I try to run software compiled with opencv, I get the following error:

`libavcodec.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Looking around `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, I can find `libavcodec.so`, but not `libavcodec.so.56`.

When trying to run `sudo apt-get install libavcodec56`, I get:

`Package 'libavcodec56' has no installation candidate`

I've scoured the internet in search of an answer, but could not find anything at this point. Any help with solving this annoying problem will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just install ffmpeg by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

And you get this files:

1. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so
2. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56
   Just copy  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56`

Comment: You just suggested (in step #2) copying the same file to itself. I'm curious what you think that would accomplish. You **probably** meant "copy `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.56`", which would work but I would argue it's better to create a symlink with `ln -s libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 libavcodec.so.56`. (An exception to the rule about not manually creating library symlinks that I mentioned in my response to @solar-gy, since `ldconfig` doesn't handle symlinks to different names, only version symlinks.)

Answer (score 1):

I will post here how I got resolved the same problem in my raspberry pi 3 when installing opencv for python, hopefully someone same the time.

**1) Make sure you don't have opencv versions other than "python-opencv" by following command.**

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep cv3
```

If above shows an output uninstalled it as follows

```
dpkg -r opencv3.1
```

"opencv3.1" should be replaced by your version.

**2) Then follow following step to install "python-opencv"**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install ipython python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pygame
```

[this blog](http://bennycheung.github.io/raspberry-pi-3-for-computer-vision) explains installation process

Answer (score 0):

The comment of FeRD allowed me to resolve the problem. 
ffmpeg was installed from source, and the ld paths were not set correctly, and pulseaudio was not starting. 
The so lib file was double sym-linked:

```
krzys@kLatitude-E6430:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 sie 23  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.so


  krzys@kLatitude-E6430:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 sie 23  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100

sudo ldconfig -vl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100
```

The last command allowed me to set symlink, and pulseaudio deamon started running.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, I was missing version symlinks to 4 shared libraries but had the correctly so libraries. You can create the missing version symlinks yourself:

```
readelf -d libavcodec.so  | grep SONAME
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56]
sudo ln -s libavcodec.so libavcodec.so.56
```

Comment: You should never manage library symlinks yourself, rather you should let `ldconfig` do it. And unless you manually installed it (incorrectly), `libavcodec.so` is a symbolic link as well (from the development package for ffmpeg), so you've just made a symlink to a symlink. What you _should've_ done is `ls -l libavcodec.so`, which would show you were the symlink is pointing to (usually something like `libavcodec.so.56.60.100`), and then run `sudo ldconfig -vl /path/to/libavcodec.so.56.60.100` which would re-create the `libavcodec.so.56` symlink pointing to that file.